# avoid duplicate values in array php for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

My array contains duplicate values ...

i tried using array_unique function but its not working..

Code below...

> while($rowTable = mysql_fetch_array($resultTable)) {
>
> ```
> $selQuery = "SELECT * FROM dump_hotelamenities WHERE HotelCode='$rowTable[HotelCode]' LIMIT 5";
> $resultQuery = mysql_query($selQuery);
>
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery))
> {
>     echo "<br> Hotel Code : " .$row['HotelCode'];
>     //$info = array();
>     $info=(str_replace('YES','',$row['PAmenities']));
>     $info_new=array();
>     $info_new =array_unique(explode(';',$info));
>
>     echo "<br> Hotel Features : " ;
>
>     print_r ($info_new);
>
>     echo "<hr>";
>
>
> } }
> ```

OUTPUT:

```
 Array ( [0] => Small pets allowed under 5 kg [1] => Small pets allowed under 5 kg [2] => Large pets allowed over 5 kg [3] => Large pets allowed over 5 kg [4] => Wheelchair-accessible [5] => Wheelchair-accessible [6] => Car park [7] => Car park [8] => Garage [9] => Garage [10] => Mobile phone coverage [11] => Wired Internet [12] => Wi-fi [13] => Transfer service [14] => Secure parking [15] => Room service [16] => Laundry service [17] => Hotel safe [18] => Cloakroom [19] => Lift access [20] => Newspaper stand [21] => Supermarket [22] => Bicycle storage [23] => Sun terrace [24] => Gym [25] => Newspapers [26] => Restaurant [27] => Non-smoking area [28] => Photocopier [29] => Sun loungers [30] => Children& [31] => apos [32] => s play area [33] => TV lounge [34] => Sauna [35] => Massage [36] => Spa treatments [37] => Year of construction - 2008 [38] => Number of floors main building - 10 [39] => Apartments - 25 [40] => Studios - 1 [41] => Connecting rooms [42] => Connecting rooms [43] => Apartment complex [44] => Nearest Bus / Metro Stop - 25000 m [45] => Ski slopes - 2000 m )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way

in your query use distinct like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name;
```

may be it will help

Comment: query has got no duplicate values..i want to remove duplicates rom the array

Comment: may your while run two time check again